# jquery - adjust all font sizes where they are declared?

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, font-size

Im detecting if the user has Calibri installed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cWidth = $('.calibri').width();
    var aWidth = $('.arial').width();
    if (cWidth == aWidth){ 
        //No Calibri installed
    }      
});
```

How would I find any classes that define the font-size and then reduce them by say 20%?

Comment: As @protonfish said, pixel precision isn't practical in web design. And, using JS to resize the text will probably make the design "jump around", every page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your javascript linked is working to this point, completing it is a matter of setting the sizes I believe (if i understood correctly), here is what should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cWidth = $('.calibri').width();
    var aWidth = $('.arial').width();
    if (cWidth == aWidth){ 
        $('div, span, input, p, h1, h2 ...etc ').each(function(i) { /* This is suspect, it needs to 
                                  select all tags*/
            if($(this).css('font-size').length) {
                var currentSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
                var newSize = currentSize * .8;
                $(this).css('font-size', newSize + " <unit> ");
            }
        });
    }      
});
```

This is questionable, but might get you closer to what you are looking for.

edit, major brain fart, you have to check for `font-size` after getting the element. This still might not be perfect (haven't been able to test it), but the idea is you need to check for a return from `$(this).css('font-size')`

Hope this helps. The more I think about it, its a pretty kludgy thing to try to do.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: whats the problem? - getting the error: `$("body").css("font-size").each` is not a function

Comment: Yeah, got aheaf of myself, give my change a shot, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS:

```
body {font-size:80%}
```

Trying to control fonts precisely on the client is a fool's game; You will spend a lot of time trying only to eventually fail. If some unholy hack existed to force your exact font, what real value would it be? Web pages are documents, not movie posters. Set your font as a generic family and move on.

```
body {font-family:sans-serif}
```

Comment: as much as I would like to do that - unfortunately I need to pay some attention to the typography of this project. `body {font-size:80%}` works for the text which hasn't been redeclared such as headings, and other content areas etc - rather than adjusting each of these separately I need to find an automated way.

Comment: Bummer. Sorry I wasn't helpful then. Good luck.